# Sum up a parameter in array if condition matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array as below.

```
    var arr = [
    {'ResId':123,'ResVal':4,'Date':'11/03/2015'},
    {'ResId':123,'ResVal':8,'Date':'11/03/2015'},
    {'ResId':123,'ResVal':4,'Date':'13/03/2015'},
    {'ResId':123,'ResVal':4,'Date':'13/03/2015'},
    {'ResId':223,'ResVal':4,'Date':'12/03/2015'},
    {'ResId':223,'ResVal':2,'Date':'12/03/2015'},
    {'ResId':223,'ResVal':4,'Date':'13/03/2015'},
    {'ResId':765,'ResVal':4,'Date':'13/03/2015'}]
```

I want to sum up the value of ResVal if both ResId and Date matches.
Suppose In above array ResId = 123 and Date = 11/03/2015 have such two entries then I'll sum up them and create one entry with ResId = 123,Date = 11/03/2015 and ResVal = 12

I would need this to be dynamic as the value of all the 3 parameters will be different all the time.

My Resulting array should be like below

```
[{'ResId':123,'ResVal':12,'Date':'11/03/2015'},
{'ResId':123,'ResVal':8,'Date':'13/03/2015'},
{'ResId':223,'ResVal':6,'Date':'12/03/2015'},
{'ResId':223,'ResVal':8,'Date':'13/03/2015'}]
```

Also I would need this to be done with pure JS/Jquery.

Comment: and what is your problem?

Comment: New to JS , confused on how do I do it.

Comment: You really need to show what you've tried instead of just coming here and telling people what you want. Programming is all about problem solving, so where exactly did you get stuck while trying to solve this problem?

Comment: the result of this `{'ResId':223,'ResVal':8,'Date':'13/03/2015'}` may be wrong ...

Answer (score 1):

This is a proposal with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
var arr = [
        { 'ResId': 123, 'ResVal': 4, 'Date': '11/03/2015' },
        { 'ResId': 123, 'ResVal': 8, 'Date': '11/03/2015' },
        { 'ResId': 123, 'ResVal': 4, 'Date': '13/03/2015' },
        { 'ResId': 123, 'ResVal': 4, 'Date': '13/03/2015' },
        { 'ResId': 223, 'ResVal': 4, 'Date': '12/03/2015' },
        { 'ResId': 223, 'ResVal': 2, 'Date': '12/03/2015' },
        { 'ResId': 223, 'ResVal': 4, 'Date': '13/03/2015' },
        { 'ResId': 765, 'ResVal': 4, 'Date': '13/03/2015' }],
    reduced = arr.reduce(function (r, a) {
        !r.some(function (b) {
            if (a.Date === b.Date && a.ResId === b.ResId) {
                b.ResVal += a.ResVal;
                return true;
            }
        }) && r.push({ ResId: a.ResId, ResVal: a.ResVal, Date: a.Date });
        return r;
    }, []);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(reduced, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```